# Assembly: problems incrementing memory location

Tags: assembly, 6502

I am just beginning 6502 assembly,  and I am trying to figure out the basics. I'm using a JavaScript emulator on my phone to assemble the code. I'm trying to get it to increment p (my memory location) and store A in both addresses (as a prelude to a loop later). But, when run, it's only storing A to $0205 and not $0206 (which is what I am trying to get it to do). Any help appreciated.

```
LDA #$01
define p $0205
STA p
INC p
STA p
```

Comment: You incremented only `p` which is $0205. You never accessed $0206.

Comment: What does `INC p` do, does it increment the memory at 0205? It can not increment p, as that is just an idea, it is not a value in memory or a register.

Comment: This is faulty high level thinking at play.  Any recommendations on how to increment the memory address itself?

Comment: @RaymondChen can you explain?

Comment: The Inc instruction increments a byte. You incremented p, which is $0205. You didn't do anything about $0206.

Comment: 6502 doesn't do pointers easily, the way more modern ISAs with registers wide enough to hold a pointer do.  See [Why do C to Z80 compilers produce poor code?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6095) for a summary of the limitations of 8-bit CPUs like 6502.  I think you want `sta p` / `sta p+1`, because `p` is only an assemble-time constant.

Comment: Another dreadful processor is the inter x86. It have bigger registers (like the z80, but with all the special purpose registers, you spend most of your instructions just moving data from register to register. At least the 6502 is nice and simple

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: maybe you haven't looked at x86 since 8086.  Since 386 added orthogonal addressing modes (where any register can be a base or index),  `movsx` and `movzx` for sign/zero extension into registers other than AX, and multiply to/from any register (e.g. `imul ebp, dword [rdi+rax*4], 12345`), x86's registers are flat/orthogonal for most purposes. The `loop` instruction is obsolete, so only a few fixed-register things are left: shift counts in CL (fixed by BMI2 `shlx` / `shrx`) and integer division.  x86-64 compiler output is not full of `mov reg,reg` because of special-purpose regs.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have not looked at much x86 code, but it was post 586. I am sure when you compare a modern x86 with a 8086, it looks so good, but I am not comparing it with that. I am comparing it with a well architected CPU, such as arm, 68000, sparc, Alpha, Mips, …

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: So am I.  x86-64 as a compiler target (orthogonal registers, etc.) is not a lot different from other modern ISAs.  ARM can be more efficient than most RISCs because of its barrel shifter allowing shifts as part of other instructions, but x86-64 can fold loads into memory operands for other insns.  I'm not saying ARM is bad or that x86-64 is a *better* ISA, but your claim about spending many instructions moving data because of special-purpose registers is total crap other than code that's full of variable-count shifts with multiple different counts.

Comment: x86 does have a significant amount of `mov` instructions, but that's because integer instructions are 2-operand, with a destructive dst/src. Not because of special-purpose registers. `lea` is a workaround for that for shift-and-add. A 3-operand ISA would very likely be more efficient, but x86's warts are manageable until something better hopefully replaces it.  It does have a pretty nice SIMD instruction set, especially with AVX512 filling in many of the gaps. ARM doesn't have efficient vector -> integer mask (`pmovmskb`) so it's hard to write ARM SIMD search loops, but NEON is otherwise ok .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have written doesn't do what you think it does. `p` is just a defined name for the number `$205`. In effect, your program is

```
LDA #$01
; define p $0205
STA $0205
INC $0205
STA $0205
```

The `INC`instruction increments the contents of location `$0205` but then it is immediately overwritten by the second `STA`.

There are several ways to do what you want. Firstly, if it is always the location `p` and the next one, depending on your assembler, you should be able to write

```
LDA #$01
define p $0205
STA p
STA p+1
```

That will put 1 in `$0205` and `$0206`. An alternative, if you want to do the incrementing at run time is to use an index register, of which there are two `X` and `Y`.

```
LDA #$01
define p $0205
LDY #0
STA p,Y
INY 
STA p,Y
```

That's not really better than the previous, but it can be used in a loop.

```
define p $0205
define count 10

    LDA #$01
    LDY #count
loop:
    DEY        ; Decrement Y by 1 setting the zero flag if zero
    STA p,Y    ; Store the result in p + Y (flags are unaffected)
    BNE loop   ; Go round the loop if the zero flag is not set
```

The above will fill the locations from p to p + 9 with the constant 1. Note that it does it by going downwards through memory.

If `p` is unknown until runtime, you can do the same thing but using a zero page indirect address.

```
define p $0205
define count 10
define ptr $50 ; A random zero page location

    LDA #$01
    LDY #count

; First load the address in the zero page location

    LDA <p     ; < is a common notation for the low byte of a 16 bit number ($05 in this case)
    STA ptr
    LDA >p     ; and > is for the high byte ($02 in this case)
    STA ptr+1

; Now a similar loop to before

loop:
    DEY        ; Decrement Y by 1 setting the zero flag if zero
    STA (ptr),Y; Store the result in p + Y (flags are unaffected)
    BNE loop   ; Go round the loop if the zero flag is not set
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you put the address(0205) into an index register (I think the 6502 has 2 of these). The store A into the address that the index register is pointing, increment the index register, and store A into the address that the index register is pointing.

Comment: I think its index registers are only 8 bits wide.  It can efficiently index relative to a fixed base for a static address, for an 8-bit index, but it doesn't have full pointer registers.  [Why do C to Z80 compilers produce poor code?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6095) describes some of the limitations (it mentions 6502 as well as z80/8080).